# Writing multiple Emails to a text file Python IMAP

Tags: python, web-applications, imap

I currently have a code that works in a pyramid web-application. By pressing a button, the web app runs a function that reads unread Emails from inbox, deletes first 6 lines (not important info) and writes them onto a file. Later, this data is used as plotting data with matplotlib. My current problem is that the code only reads one unread Email at a time. This means that if I have for example 5 unread emails with data that I want to write to a file, the press of the button only writes the data of one Email, while I want the data from all 5 Emails.

Is there any possible way to read all unread Emails at once and write them onto a text file? I've been thinking about adding code that counts the amount of unread emails, and it keeps looping the read/write function until the unread amount reaches 0. There might be a more professional way to do this, so that's why I ask. Thanks in advance!

Here is my current code:

```
@view_config(route_name='update-data')
def update_view(request):

    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    m.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
    m.list()
    m.select('inbox')

    result, data = m.uid('search', None, 'FROM', '"senderEmail"', 'UNSEEN') # Only unseen mail

    i = len(data[0].split()) #space separate string

    if i == 0:
        return Response('<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styleplot.css"/></head>'
        + '<h3> Data cannot be updated </h3><h4>No new emails</h4>'
        + '<form class="anchor" action="http://localhost:8888"><input class="homebutton" type="submit" value="Return" /></form>')

    for x in range(i):
        latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
        result, email_data = m.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)



        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                with open('C:/Email/file.txt', 'a') as myfile:  # Opens file.txt and writes the email body
                    myfile.write(str(body)) 
                with open('C:/Email/file.txt', 'r+') as f:  # Opens file.txt again in read mode and reads lines
                    lines = f.readlines()
                    with open ('C:/Email/newfile.txt','a') as g: # Writes file.txt contents to newfile.txt, starting from line 6, deletes contents of the first file
                        g.writelines(lines[6:])
                        f.truncate(0)
            else:
                continue




            return Response('<h3>Data update successful</h3>'
            + '<form class="anchor" action="http://localhost:8888"><input class="homebutton" type="submit" value="Return" /></form>')
```

Comment: The method you suggested in your post sounds fine enough. You can read them all into a temporary variable of some sort, and then do whatever you like with all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because you are writing and reading in the same iteration of the `for` ... at the same indentation level. Basically on each iteration you are:

- getting an email
- write to the file
- read that file (seems useless at this point just use the body)
- still "here", after reading the file you write to another file and truncate the first.

To make things worst you have the `return` also under the `for` ... so you are returning on the first iteration.
I think your code should be more like

```
@view_config(route_name='update-data')
def update_view(request):

    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    m.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
    m.list()
    m.select('inbox')

    result, data = m.uid('search', None, 'FROM', '"senderEmail"', 'UNSEEN') # Only unseen mail

    i = len(data[0].split()) #space separate string

    if i == 0:
        return Response('<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styleplot.css"/></head>'
        + '<h3> Data cannot be updated </h3><h4>No new emails</h4>'
        + '<form class="anchor" action="http://localhost:8888"><input class="homebutton" type="submit" value="Return" /></form>')

    for latest_email_uid in data[0].split():
        result, email_data = m.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
        with open('C:/Email/file.txt', 'a') as myfile:  # Opens file.txt and writes the email body
            for part in email_message.walk():
                if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                    myfile.write(str(body)) 

    with open('C:/Email/file.txt', 'r+') as f:  # Opens file.txt again in read mode and reads lines
        lines = f.readlines()
        with open ('C:/Email/newfile.txt','a') as g: # Writes file.txt contents to newfile.txt, starting from line 6, deletes contents of the first file
            g.writelines(lines[6:])
        f.truncate(0)



    return Response('<h3>Data update successful</h3>'
        + '<form class="anchor" action="http://localhost:8888"><input class="homebutton" type="submit" value="Return" /></form>')
```

Later edit: I don't really know what's the reasoning of writing in the intermediary file, I think the real problem in you code might've been the "wrong" indentation of the `return`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I'm relatively new to Python and I am a noob coder in general, didn't realize to point that out in my original post. I'll try your version out and i'll give the feedback once I've tested it! Thanks